# ignore the conversion process for unnecessary fields in spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I have a criteria jsp page which is searched by date or name or status etc. They all fields are not mandatory fields. When I search by name and skip the other fields, I got the `ConversionFailedException` for other fields such as `Date`. I want to skip the conversion process for the unnecessary fields in spring MVC.

I use Spring MVC form and JSP.

Comment: you can use field validation. If the field is empty, just don't convert it.

Comment: yes, but I think the spring container does the conversion process first and validation process later. In my page, it may convert empty string into date object first and the exception throw.